# From algebraic group actions to group scheme actions

Tags: algebraic-groups, group-schemes, geometric-invariant-theory

I am trying to understand the basic results of geometric invariant theory. I want to pull off the band aid and use Mumford, but am a neophyte with respect to scheme theory. Thus, I have been trying to supplement with Dolgachev's "Lectures on Invariant Theory," but I am unsteady with regards to passing back and forth between them. I then have several questions, any of which may be obvious to the expert. If needed I can split them up, but they are all related.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group acting rationally on an affine algebraic set $X$ via $$m_X:G\times X\rightarrow X.$$ $G$ can be viewed as a (smooth connected) group scheme $G$ over $k$ and $X$ has an associated affine k-scheme $X/k$ determined by taking the spectrum of the coordinate ring $R(X)$.

1. Does the action $m_X$ always promote to an action $$m_{X/k}:G \times_k X/k \rightarrow X_k?$$ If not, under what conditions does this work? For $g\in G$, it seems perfectly reasonable to define $m_{X/k}(g,x)=m_X(g,x)$ for all ordinary points $x\in X/k$, but what about the generic points? Can I simply define $m_{X/k}(g,x')=x'$ for all generic points $x'\in X/k$?
2. Assuming $m_X$ can be promoted to an action $m_{X/k}$, under what conditions on $m_X$ is $m_{X/k}$ closed as in Mumford's definition 0.8? The orbits of $G$ on $X$ are smooth and closed (Humphreys, Linear Algebraic Groups, p. 60, 8.3), so if Mumford's geometric points are just the ordinary points this works, but I'd wager this is missing something.
3. Now suppose that $G$ is reductive. If $m_{X}$ promotes to an action $m_{X/k}$, then the universal categorical quotient $(Y/k,\phi_{X/k})$ exists (Mumford, p. 27,Theorem 1.1). By construction (Dolgachev, p. 95, Theorem 6.1) I also have a quotient $(Y,\phi_X)$. It seems immediate that $Y/k$ is $Spec(R(Y))$. Conversely, given a quotient $(Z, \psi_X)$ of $X$ by $G$, I can construct $Z/k:=Spec(R(Z))$. Does this imply that a categorical quotient $(Z/k,\psi_{X/k})$ (and necessarily an action $m_{X/k}$) exists? If the answer to question 1 is yes, then the answer must be yes. If the answer to 1 is no, then this question is equivalent to asking if $m_{X}$ always promotes to an $m_{X/k}$ when $G$ is reductive.
4. If $m_{X/k}$ is closed, then $(Y/k, \phi_{X/k})$ is a geometric quotient as defined by Mumford. Chasing definitions this would seem to imply that $(Y,\phi_X)$ is a geometric quotient according to Dolgachev. Conversely, if $(Z,\psi_X)$ is a geometric quotient, does a geometric quotient $(Z/k,\psi_{X/k})$ exist? Equivalently, for $G$ reductive, is the existence of a closed $m_{X/k}$ equivalent to $(Z,\psi_X)$ being a geometric quotient?

Comment: As I understand, $X/k$ is not the same thing as $X$. The former should have strictly more points than the latter - those new ones corresponding to irreducible subvarieties. The question is then about whether or not there is a subtlety in defining the action of $G$ on those new points.

Comment: By affine algebraic set I mean a subset of an affine k-space corresponding to the set of common zeroes to a system of polynomial equations.

Comment: The functor sending a reduced scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field to the associated algebraic variety (forget the nonclosed points) is an equivalence of categories, so the answer to your first question is yes. Most things work the same in the two categories, but you have to be careful about constructions, e.g., fibred products, that can take you outside the category of reduced schemes. Mumford's Red Book is a good place to look for such things.